# Rails: force column update for routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, routes

I've got a route constraint that matches column values. Works fine, but it seems to cache the values so that new values don't match. How can I force a reload for this class?

```
class ClientCodeConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    @client_code = request.path_parameters[:client_code]
    users.each { |u| return true if @client_code == u.client_code }
    false
  end

  private

  def users
    @users ||= User.all
  end
end
```

I need to force update it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your code seems to be very bad. If it possible, you should make just one DB query instead of retrieving all users.

```
class ClientCodeConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    User.where(client_code: request.path_parameters[:client_code]).any?
  end
end
```

I think the problem is here `@users ||= User.all`. You are caching User.all result in instance variable, so it does not updated. You don't need to use instance variable at all. Choose your users method to:

```
def users
  User.all
end
```

Or if it possible, just use my solution.

Comment: Ah, that's so much better. Thanks.